# Running a ProgressDialog MonoAndroid

Tags: android, xamarin.android, threadpool, progressdialog

I am trying to run a progressDialog that will loading items into a Sqlite datebase on a first load for my application.  I get an error message because the application runs the rest of the code in the application before the rest of the data is loaded into the database.

How do I make sure the code is completed in the progressDialog before the code in the rest of the program?

```
LocalDatabase DB = new LocalDatabase();
var dbpd = ProgressDialog.Show(this, "Loading Database", "Please wait Loading Data",true);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((s) =>{
DB.createDB();
RunOnUiThread(() => databaseLoaded());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ayncTask for this

```
class loadDatabase extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(Void result) {
            //Start the dialog
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //Do the database loading part..
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            //Dismiss the dialog and proceed furture.
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }
```

To execute this, call execute on its new object.